# GC content un Python

Tags: python

I have this program to generate random N sequences and find the GC content.

```
import random

def randseq(abc, length):
    return "".join([random.choice(abc) for i in range(random.randint(1, length))])
N = 2
longest_seq = ""
shortest_seq = randseq("ATCG", 10)
for i in range(N):
    print(f'Sequence {i +1}):')
    seq = randseq("ATCG", 10)
    if len(seq) > len(longest_seq):
        longest_seq = seq
    if len(seq) < len(shortest_seq):
        shortest_seq = seq
    totalG = seq.count("G")
    totalC = seq.count("C")
    GCcontent = totalG + totalC
    print(seq)

print("The GC content is:", GCcontent)
```

This is the output:

Sequence 1):

TCGGTG

Sequence 2):

GCATCGTCAA

The GC content is: 5

```
When I print the GC content, it does not make sense. The content should be: Cs = 4 + Gs = 5, Total = 9. What's wrong with the code? Also how can I show the result of sequences
in a dictionary? for example: Sequence 1: {A:0, T:2, C:1, G:3}
```

Comment: Think you meant: `GCcontent += totalG + totalC`.  The current expression is providing the count of the last sequence rather than the cumulative.

Comment: @DarrylG When I run GCcontent += totalG + totalC, it give me an error: GCcontent is not defined.

Comment: See posted answer.

Comment: Check updated answer (error in previous).

Comment: @DarrylG how can I print: The longest sequences is: Sequence number 2? instead of showing the AACAATAC.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Does the more compact version make sense?

Comment: @DarrylG It makes sense. Thank you for helping me. I am new in this field and this task was a complete challenge.

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to ping me if you have any future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code correction plus output of counts as requested.

```
import random
from collections import Counter

def randseq(abc, length):
    return "".join([random.choice(abc) for i in range(random.randint(1, length))])
N = 2

GCcontent = 0
sequences = []
for i in range(N):
    print(f'Sequence {i +1}):')
    seq = randseq("ATCG", 10)
    sequences.append(seq)
    
    totalG = seq.count("G")
    totalC = seq.count("C")
    GCcontent += totalG + totalC
    print(f'\tSequence: {seq}')
    print(f'\tCounts: {Counter(seq)}')
    print()
    

shortest_seq = min(sequences, key = len)
longest_seq = max(sequences, key = len)
print(f"The GC content is: {GCcontent}")
print(f"Longest sequence is sequence number: {sequences.index(longest_seq) + 1}")
print(f"Shortest sequence is sequence number: {sequences.index(shortest_seq) + 1}")
```

**Example Run**

```
Sequence 1):
    Sequence: GCAGATAGC
    Counts: Counter({'G': 3, 'A': 3, 'C': 2, 'T': 1})

Sequence 2):
    Sequence: ACT
    Counts: Counter({'A': 1, 'C': 1, 'T': 1})

The GC content is: 6
Longest sequence is sequence number: 1
Shortest sequence is sequence number: 2
```

**Code Refactoring**

The above code can be rewritten more succinctly as follows.

```
import random
from collections import Counter

def randseq(abc, length):
    return "".join([random.choice(abc) for i in range(random.randint(1, length))])

N = 2
sequences = [randseq("ATCG", 10) for _ in range(N)]   # N sequences
counts = [Counter(seq) for seq in sequences]          # count of letters of all sequences

for i, seq in enumerate(sequences, start = 1):
    print(f'\nSequence {i}):\n\tSequence: {seq}\n\tCounts: {Counter(seq)}')
 
    
shortest_seq = min(sequences, key = len)
longest_seq = max(sequences, key = len)
GCcontent = sum(cnt['G'] + cnt['C'] for cnt in counts)
print(f"\nThe GC content is: {GCcontent}")
print(f"Longest sequence is sequence number: {sequences.index(longest_seq) + 1}")
print(f"Shortest sequence is sequence number: {sequences.index(shortest_seq) + 1}")
```